# Choosing label placement in MultiPolygon with CartoCSS

Tags: labeling, tilemill, cartocss, multi-polygon, denmark

I am rendering an interactive world map with TileMill and I have the problem that the country name for Denmark is placed onto Greenland. This is because Denmark is represented as a MultiPolygon with polygons for Denmark proper and Greenland, as Greenland is a territorial dependency of Denmark, and because TileMill only places one text label onto a MultiPolygon.

My question is if it is possible to influence with TileMill's CartoCSS on which of a MultiPolygon's subpolygons the textlabel is placed. I'd prefer for the text label to appear on continental Denmark.

I have tried the

```css
text-placement-type: simple;
text-placements: 'E,W';
```

properties, hoping that this would select the more east or westward polygon, but to no avail.

I have also looked for a way to position a textlabel at an absolute position, but this also does not seem to be possible.

Finally, I would like to avoid manipulating the shapefile, as I am taking it from an external source.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add centroids then I think you could use these rules to influence Denmark's label specifically:

```css
text-dy: 1;
text-dx: 1;
```